# OpenLDAP CentOS7 rejects authenication sometimes

Tags: single-sign-on, openldap, centos7

I try to setup an OpenLDAP-Server that I can use as backend for a WebSSO (LemonLDAP::NG). This specific WebSSO allows to store the sessions inside the LDAP backend.
My problem is that it seems that whenever I connect to the LDAP backend to store session data ~1 out of 10 times it works, the other times LDAP rejects the authentication.
[Logs for failed attempts and for successful attempts can be found here](http://mail.ow2.org/wws/arc/lemonldap-ng-users/2015-12/msg00002.html)

As you can see the maker of LemonLDAP::NG thinks the error is within OpenLDAP (or my configuration of OpenLDAP). I'm out of ideas and open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone changes OpenLDAP DB during your session. Don't you have any processes with access to MDB file except this instance of OpenLDAP?
It may be slapadd/slapmodify/2nd slapd instance with the same `directory` value in config.

If not, could you show your slapd.conf (don't forget to change `rootpw`)

Comment: It is a clean installation and no other process is running. Since all configuration is located inside the ldap Store there is no slapd.conf.
This is a test system that will be wiped clean an all passwords will change even the IP will be different I can grant you access to the system so you can look around. This is my Facebook Profile for contact: https://www.facebook.com/iam.swtrse

Comment: Logs you offered show that monitored instance of `slapd` unexpectedly can't read value that was just read. It can be caused by:

* OpenLDAP error (trust me, there are a lot of them)
* OS errors (someone might modify DB file)
* replication process (I don't know your config)

So I recommend to enable auditlog, reproduce the trouble and analyze what modification were during test.

<code>
    # auditlog
    overlay auditlog
    auditlog /path/to/var/log/audit.log
</code>